# Convert CATransform3D into CIVector's for CIPerspectiveTransform, replace UIGetScreenImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, gpuimage, catransform3d

Is it possible to convert a `CATransform3D` into a set of `CIVectors` in order to transform a `UIImage` with a `CATransform3D`?

I believe that is now finally possible to replace `UIGetScreenImage()`'s ability to flatten 3D transforms of `UIView/CALayer` into an image by traversing the view hierarchy and rendering individual images, and then applying the `CATransform3D` to the image that was created.

I started working with `GPUImage`, which does accept `CATransform3Ds` to apply to a `UIImage` and unfortunately had no luck. Attached is the code I was using, and links to the images that were produced.

[Screenshot of Simulator](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1182042/451908/eb7c31be-b2c0-11e2-977c-58498aca377b.png)

[Image Produced](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1182042/451907/eb72c502-b2c0-11e2-8e38-a8a800fed370.png)

```
- (UIImage*)iterateLayerHierarchy:(CALayer*)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(layer.frame.size.width,
                                                      layer.frame.size.height),
                                           NO,
                                           0.0);


    for (CALayer *sublayer in layer.sublayers)
    {
        UIImage* subImage;

        if (sublayer.sublayers.count > 1) {
            subImage = [self iterateLayerHierarchy:sublayer];
        } else {
            subImage = [UIView getImageFromLayer:sublayer];
        }
        CGRect imageRect;
        if (isRetina()) {
            imageRect = CGRectMake(sublayer.position.x-subImage.size.width/4,
                                   sublayer.position.y-subImage.size.height/4,
                                   subImage.size.width,
                                   subImage.size.height);
        }else{
            imageRect = CGRectMake(sublayer.position.x-subImage.size.width/2,
                                   sublayer.position.y-subImage.size.height/2,
                                   subImage.size.width,
                                   subImage.size.height);
        }
        [subImage drawInRect:imageRect];
        //sublayer.hidden = YES;
    }

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}


+ (UIImage*) getImageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(layer.bounds.size.width,
                                                      layer.bounds.size.height),
                                           NO,
                                           0.0);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (!CATransform3DEqualToTransform(layer.transform, CATransform3DIdentity))
    {
        GPUImageTransformFilter *transformFilter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc] init];
        transformFilter.transform3D = layer.transform;
        img = [transformFilter imageByFilteringImage:img];
    }

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible to calculate the `CIVector`s for a `CIPerspectiveTransform`, but you really do not want to do that. `CIPerspectiveTransform` is buggy. Don't believe me? Just swap your bottom and top coordinates for an image, this will fail. (You will get some sort of square thingie).

Comment: I've been trying, apparently the CIVector for a CIPerspectiveTransform is just asking for corner points, with an X,Y value. I got those by using convertPoint:toLayer, but it's not quite right. I'm not sure if it's buggy, or that I'm just not doing it quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct answer to the question, as of iOS 7 there is no longer a need to solve this problem. "UIGetScreenImage()" has effectively been replaced by "drawViewHierarchyInRect:", which is able to capture both OpenGL layers and UIKit based views simultaneously.